# How to make a rectangle tangent to a circle

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to make a rectangle object to go around a circle, with the rectangle always tangent to the circle where it is going around. I have the code that will make it go around the circle, but I don't see how to make it tangent to it. This is how it looks so far. [image: currently looks]

I am using an animation timer, since I don't know the full path that the rectangle will follow as it can change if I it finds something blocking it. 
I can make the rectangle go around the circle in a smooth way, but I don't know how to make the rectangle tangent to it.

```
 public void moveInCircle(double radius)
   {

  double newX = getX() + (radius * Math.cos(Math.toDegrees(angle)));
  double newY = getY() + (radius * Math.sin(Math.toDegrees(angle)));
  vehicle.setTranslateX(newX);
  vehicle.setTranslateY(newY);

   }
```

I know that the tangent will be the adjacent side(x) divided by the opposite side (y), but I don't understand how to incorporate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend using a `Rotate` transform. This way you only need to set the initial position and the pivot point and can restrict the updates to the `Rotate.angle` property.

The following example uses a `Timeline` to animate the property, but this could easily be done from the `moveCircle` method by using `rotate.setAngle(angleDegrees);`:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Pane root = new Pane();
    root.setMinSize(500, 500);

    final double radius = 150;
    final double centerX = 250;
    final double centerY = 250;
    final double height = 40;

    Circle circle = new Circle(centerX, centerY, radius, null);
    circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

    // rect starts at the rightmost point of the circle touching it with the left midpoint
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(centerX + radius, centerY - height / 2, 10, height);
    rect.setFill(Color.RED);

    Rotate rotate = new Rotate(0, centerX, centerY); // pivot point matches center of circle

    rect.getTransforms().add(rotate);

    // animate one rotation per 5 sec 
    Timeline animation = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(rotate.angleProperty(), 0d)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), new KeyValue(rotate.angleProperty(), 360d)));
    animation.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    animation.play();

    root.getChildren().addAll(circle, rect);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

---

Btw: the following part of your code seems odd

```
double newX = getX() + (radius * Math.cos(Math.toDegrees(angle)));
double newY = getY() + (radius * Math.sin(Math.toDegrees(angle)));
```

`Math.sin` and `Math.cos` expect radians, not degree. You either need to use `toRadians` or don't require a conversion...

Comment: You're right on the last part of code....strangely it works. I need to work that part. I will need to make the vehicle change lane, I am thinking of making it rotate, go straight until it's positioned in the centre of the next lane and then rotate so that it can follow the new lane where it changed to. Timeline seems to have more advantages over using the animation timer in that way, since I can use inbuilt methods, instead of having to make my own methods for rotation and follow a circular path.